# nodejs get previous time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, I know you can do something like this:

```
prev.mtime
```

In side of the `fs.watchFile` function, but that will return the date formated with something like this:

```
Fri Aug 02 2013 17:40:28 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

But I would like to get the previous timestamp line in milliseconds.

Comment: +new Date(prev.mtime)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

wow, nevermind... I got it:

```
console.dir(prev.mtime.getTime());
console.dir(curr.mtime.getTime());
```

That was easy!

Comment: That's the answer I gave 3 hours ago, when you asked.

Comment: You should probably accept Dan's answer. He answered correctly and gave some explanation regarding your problem and his answer.

Answer (score 5):

`prev.mtime` is a JavaScript `Date` object. What you're seeing is the default string representation of the object. You can use its `getTime()` method to get the timestamp in milliseconds.

References:

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date